# boolean値が勝手に代入されてる気がします

Tags: java

トグルを作りたいので以下のコードを書き、インスタンス化をして、何回か`toggle()`を呼び出しました。
`true` `false` `true` `false` みたいに交互に出力されてほしいのですが、なぜか `false`が連続してでてきます。助けてください。

```java
package client.mod;

public class Mod {
    
    private boolean toggled;
    
    
    public void toggle() {
        System.out.println(this.toggled);
        this.toggled = !this.toggled;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ご提示の`Mod`クラスには問題がないように思えます。

おそらく使う側の問題でしょう。たとえば、使う側でループを回していて、ループ内で毎回 `Mod` のインスタンスを作ったりしていると、`false`が連続して表示されます。

```java
// 問題ある使いかた
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // ループ内で毎回Modのインスタンスを作っている
        Mod m = new Mod();
        m.toggle();
    } 
}
```

その場合はループに入るより前に `Mod` のインスタンスを作れば解決します。

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ループに入るより前にModのインスタンスを作る
    Mod m = new Mod();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        m.toggle();
    } 
}
```